# Define default values in angularjs form, validation doesnt'work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm lost about define default values in my form : http://1ffa3ba638.url-de-test.ws/zombieReport/partials/popup.html

validation doesnt'work too...

```
/*********************************** SubmitCtrl ***********************************/
app.controller('SubmitCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    /* data pre-define : date & url for test */
    $scope.myForm = {};
    $scope.myForm.date = new Date();
    $scope.myForm.url = "prout";

    /* ng-show things */
    $scope.successMailZR = false;
    $scope.errorMailZR = false;

    $scope.send = function() {
        if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    };

}]);
```

What is the correct way for define default values ?

---

edit :

for url i do it like this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="{{myForm.url}}" value="{{myForm.url}}" ng-model="myForm.url" readonly="readonly" />
```

it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a conflict between a binding model `$scope.myForm` and the form name `<form name="myForm"`.

Angular will assign the form's controller into the `$scope` as its name i.e. `$scope.myForm` and that override what you have initialized.

Change your form name or the binding variable to have a different name.

Comment: Ok i can see default values like that, but i see in batarang i have now two arrays of data, and validation doesnt'work :/

Comment: I think you forget to rename the `myForm` to `myFormZR` in `ng-show` of validation messages.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML:

```
<input value="default">
```

Or using Angular's ng-model:

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
    <input ng-model="value">
</div>

function YourCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'default';
}
```

Comment: @JoDiii That's just how you *set* the default value in html. In that case, I'm defining the default value as `'default'`. You could also set it to be some object.

Comment: That's the way i do it, i put the value in array of the form and it's not working. In batarang i see the array it's empty, always when i update it